# BETWEEN query on php date not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM logs;

idDate accNum    idMonths dDay dYear dType    transacted_money dat
     4 862065095        9    8  2015 Withdraw             2323 09/08/2015
     5 862065095        9    8  2015 Deposit               333 09/08/2015
```

Please help me solve this problem I wanted to get the data so that I could manipulate them in PHP. But first I would like to test my query in mysql and that's what it came out. Theres no result. Why? is my query wrong ?

Well I guess my first picture was deleted the actual query that was done was

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE dat BETWEEN '9/8/2015' AND '9/13/2015';
```

Comment: You haven't posted your query. The query shown in PHPMyAdmin doesn't attempt to do anything with dates.

Comment: *is my query wrong ?* ... where is it? can't see any query. instead of a pic consider posting the query in text format.

Comment: Im sorry i was just editing a while ago

Comment: It shows no result after I've tried the query.

Comment: Is your `dat` field a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column?  For things like `BETWEEN` to work, it needs to be a "temporal" column.  P.S. In `DATE` fields, the date would be saved as `"2015-09-08"`.

Comment: Your `dat`value is a varchar?

Comment: The dat was actually a varchar type. if i consider replacing it on a dash (-) than slash, would it work?

Comment: Yes, that's default format `MySQL` uses `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @Roch: I'd suggest saving dates in a `DATE` field.  That makes it easier to use `BETWEEN` (and even other date-based functions/operators).

Comment: Thank you guys it work. I truncated the table and back from the start i upvote you all

Answer (score 3):

Your dates are strings, not actual mysql dates, so they're being compared by **STRING** rules, which means:

```
'9/1/15' > '10/1/15' --> TRUE  (september comes after october?)
```

because `9` is bigger than `1` in a string context.

Note that

```
'2015-09-01' > '2015-10-01' -> FALSE
```

Either fix your table to convert those varchar fields into proper `date`/`datetime` fields, or you'll have do silly hacks like

```
WHERE str_to_date(varcharfield, ...) BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-10-'01'
```

note the format the dates in the above example. MySQL expects/requires dates to be in `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format to parse them as dates. Anything else is simply a string.

```
mysql> select '9/1/15' > '10/1/15', '2015-09-01' > '2015-10-01';
+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| '9/1/15' > '10/1/15' | '2015-09-01' > '2015-10-01' |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+
|                    1 |                           0 |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( `createdon` , '%Y-%m-%d' ) <= '2014-07-31'
AND DATE_FORMAT( `createdon` , '%Y-%m-%d' ) >= '2014-07-01'
```

31-07 is end date and 01-07 is start date

Answer (score 0):

As several users pointed out this is a very bad way to do it since your dates are strings and don't follow the correct way mysql formats dates, but since you asked for it this is a way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE
STR_TO_DATE(my_date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2015-09-09' AND '2015-09-12';
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58341c/1)

P.S. To use `BETWEEN` you must provide a date like `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.